# Dealing with checkboxes inside dropzone form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the dropzone.js inside a form to be able to upload images and a lot of data at once. I'm sending all the form data along with the files with the code below. Just tried to add some checkboxes but looks like this formdata append breaks it, because the checkbox values are always '1', doesn't matter if I check it or not. I don't really know how else should I append all the data, because I have a lot of inputs, select tags, and these work just fine, but the checkboxes aren't.
This is how I append the form:

```
this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
    $(":input[name]", $("form")).each(function() {
        formData.append(this.name, $(':input[name=' + this.name + ']', $("form")).val());
    });
});
```

this is one of my checkboxes:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="front-disc-brake" name="front-disc-brake">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="front-disc-brake">Front disc brake</label>
</div>
```

Comment: add in your post some error message.

Comment: There are no error messages. It just gives value '1' to each checkboxes, even if it's not checked. The problem is, I don't know how else should I append their values to the form.

Comment: If you already verified the value before appending and the problem is not there, so save the value before append and after append change it with that value by js.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: You have to check if the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: And how should I append it to the form?

Comment: Either loop over checkboxes and other field types separately, or check the `type` of the input element inside your loop that you have there, and then handle checkboxes differently in that place then. The _value_ of a checkbox is _always_ the one you specified, regardless of whether the checkbox is actually checked, or not. So you need to specifically check the checked status for checkbox elements here, and _not_ just append their value to the submission data set in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I successfully solved it with your suggestion.